# Go - Passing an array to a function receiving argument list

Tags: function, go, interface, parameter-passing

How can I pass an array as interface{} argument list in go?

```
func Yalla(i...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(i...)
}

func main() {
    Yalla(1,2,3)
    Yalla([]int{1,2,3})
}
```

Will output:

```
1 2 3 //good
[1 2 3] //bad
```

This:

```
Yalla([]int{1,2,3}...)
```

Will generate an error.

I know I can make a new interface array and assign the values one by one to solve this, but is there an elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no elegant shortcut for converting from an array of integers to a slice of interface{}. You need to write the for loop.

The call

```
Yalla([...]int{1,2,3}...)
```

does not compile because an array of integers and a slice of interface{} are different types. You can easily create a slice over the array using `[:]`:

```
Yalla([...]int{1,2,3}[:]...)
```

but this does not solve the problem because a slice of integers and a slice of interface{} are different types [as explained in the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface).

You either need to copy the values as [shown in the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface), start with a slice of interface{}

```
Yalla([]interface{}{1,2,3}...)
```

or change the variadic argument type to int

```
func Yalla(i ...int) {

}
```

if that's what you are always passing.

Comment: As I wrote, "I know I can make a new interface array and assign the values one by one", but that doesn't answer my question regarding the i...interface{} function signature, which was maybe meant to allow more flexibility?

Comment: @Ronna I think it answers the question perfectly. A varargs of `interface{}` is different than a varargs of `int` in Go, it's just the way the language was designed. Go doesn't support generics as a design choice, so this is the best you have right now. If you want to auto-expand an array or slice into a varargs, they have to be of the same type, which means you have to manually unbox and re-box it.

Comment: @JasonCoco - he edited his answer. I replied his original text.